# How to divide a 64-bit number by another 64-bit number in asmjit library code?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, asmjit

I tried:

```
  a.mov (EAX, R10);
  a.xor_ (EDX, EDX);        /* clear the upper 64 bit */
  a.idiv (R9);
  a.mov (R8, EAX);
```

Both numbers are signed int64 numbers, and the result is stored in R8. The calculation should be: R8 = R8 / R9.
My code gives wrong results. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Was this supposed to be an unsigned division? Or is it supposed to be signed? This code is sort of a mix of both

Comment: Both numbers are signed int64 numbers.

Comment: First mov R8 to RAX (don't use EAX): `a.mov (RAX, R8);` `a.xor_ (EDX, EDX);` `a.div (R9);` `a.mov (R8, RAX);`

Comment: @SepRoland: That's correct for unsigned, doing zero-extension of the dividend.  But both inputs are `int64_t` (according to the OP's comment) so you want `cqo` to sign-extend RAX into RDX:RAX before `idiv`.

Comment: @user2759621: Have you looked at how compilers do this, to know what instruction sequence you want to JIT?  https://godbolt.org/z/WjnPveWjh  That's a good step if your attempt doesn't work and you miss the important clues in the documentation (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/idiv) for the instruction (like what the implicit operands are).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> R8 = R8 / R9
> ```
>
> Both numbers are **signed** int64 numbers

You don't seem to load RAX from R8, and you don't sign-extend before doing the `idiv` instruction.

```
a.mov (RAX, R8);
a.cqo;
a.idiv (R9);
a.mov (R8, RAX);
```

> ```
> a.mov (R8, EAX);
> ```

The quotient in in RAX not just in EAX.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered me! It helped me a lot! Thanks for the godbolt link, I will check it out! Thanks!